# Check a Component content is visible Typescript - Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a modal that is in the DOM under a component that will show it up when you do a click to a button. What I'd like to know is whether there is a way to see if the component is actually being displayed on the screen or not.

In my example I have a boostrap 4 modal that will show when I click so in theory I should be able to determine if the class "show" is present or now inside the component that has the actual modal. Having said that. To achieve that I'm implementing the `AfterViewChecked` hook but when I click the parent component to toggle the modal it still hasn't updated the page and the class "show" is not in the classList for some reason (or I am doing something wrong).

The weird thing about this is that if I print the classList I have this:

```
["modal", value: "modal"]
length
:
2
value
:
"modal show"
0
:
"modal"
1
:
"show"
```

and right after it I do: `element.classList.contains("show")` and that returns `false`!

Is there any other way to get that state of the modal from the typescript component?

UPDATE:

The `AfterViewChecked` implementation:

```
public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        const modalElement = document.getElementById("imageModal");

        console.log(modalElement.classList);

        console.log(modalElement.classList.contains("show"));
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="modal" id="imageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center modal-size" role="document">
            <div data-dismiss="modal">
                <img class="modal-content" [src]="image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div *ngFor="let image of project.images, let i = index" class="carousel-item" [ngClass]="{'active' : i == 0}">
                <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal" (click)="zoom(image)" [src]="image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

The modal is after the carousel on that component template HTML:

```
<modal-image [image]="selectedImage"></modal-image>
```

where `zoom(image)`:

```
public zoom(image: string) {
        this.selectedImage = image;
    }
```

Comment: show some code, where you show the modal and check the class

Comment: I have updated the question with some code

Comment: where is this _have a boostrap 4 modal that will show when I click_ part?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I just added it